# ReplacePart behaves strangely for a list of replacements

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

Let's have a list:

```
d={0.00144444, 17.6365, 6.68574, 22.5808, -1.85266, -11.1622, 100.021, 1.}
```

I want to replace some parts of it by zeroes:
Documentation of [`ReplacePart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html) says:

```
ReplacePart[expr,{i,j,…}->new]
```

replaces the part at position `{i,j,…}`. 
but

```
ReplacePart[d, {1, 4, 5, 6, 7} -> 0.0]
```

produces

```
{0.00144444, 17.6365, 6.68574, 22.5808, -1.85266, -11.1622, 100.021, 1.}
```

and to make things stranger

```
ReplacePart[d, {{1}, 4, 5, 6, 7} -> 0.0]
{0., 17.6365, 6.68574, 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.}
```

but

```
ReplacePart[d, {1, {4}, 5, 6, 7} -> 0.0]

During evaluation of ReplacePart::pkspec1: The expression {4} cannot be used as a part specification.
(* {0.00144444, 17.6365, 6.68574, 22.5808, -1.85266, -11.1622, \
100.021, 1.} *)
```

Is this a bug? What is the proper syntax for `ReplacePart` in my situation?

Comment: Anyway, I'm pretty sure that you want `ReplacePart[data[[1, 1]], {{1}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}} -> 0.0]` rather than `ReplacePart[data[[1, 1]], {1, 4, 5, 6, 7} -> 0.0]`? `ReplacePart[data[[1, 1]], {{1}, 4, 5, 6, 7} -> 0.0]` is weird, though.

Comment: @march I appologize, it was reckless, it has been corrected. The list to replace is 1 dimensional as was defined previously, the `data[[1,1]] = d` effectively.

Comment: "replaces the part at position {i,j,…}" not "replaces parts at positions {i,j,…}"

Comment: @Kuba Is that supposed to mean at position `[[i,j,...]]`? `{i,j,..}` specifies a list, not a position, no?

Comment: @leosenko I'd look for tips in `Position` docs because `[[]]` is from `Part`.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use `Part` itself?

```
d = {0.00144444, 17.6365, 6.68574, 22.5808, -1.85266, -11.1622, 100.021, 1.}; 
d[[{1, 4, 5, 6, 7}]] = 0;
```

Now:

```
d
{0, 17.6365, 6.68574, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.}
```

If you really want to use ReplacePart:

```
ReplacePart[d, Thread[{1, 4, 5, 6, 7} -> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}]]
```

gives the same answer.